# Getting 'executable file not found in $PATH' error when running 'go run' command with exec.Command in golang container

Tags: docker, go, exec

I have a golang docker container. My Dockerfile contains:

`FROM docker.io/golang:1.21.7-alpine3.19 AS builder`

In my local everthing works fine. I can run this command in my golang project:

`cmd := exec.Command("go", "run", "anotherProgram.go", param1, param2)`

But when I run this command in my docker container, I get this error:

`exec: 'go': executable file not found in $PATH`

I am sure 'anotherProgram.go' file exist in my container. What is the problem? How can I run another go file in my golang docker container?

Comment: Usually you'd compile it (with `go build`) ahead of time, and just run it.  It's unusual for images for Go-based applications to actually contain the Go toolchain (the `go` command).

Comment: anotherProgram.go -> this file will change every 24 hours while the container is running. So that's why I need to run anotherProgram.go file. I also tried with executable file. -> cmd := exec.Command("./anotherProgram.", param1, param2). But it didn't worked. I get -> exec format error in my docker container.

Comment: Probably add /usr/local/go/bin to PATH inside the container?

Comment: The `AS builder` indicates that you are running a multi-stage build. Presumably the final image is not based on docker.io/golang, so it's not surprising that it doesn't contain the go command.

Answer (score 0):

I added these lines to my Dockerfile:

```
COPY --from=builder /usr/local/go/ /go
ENV GOROOT=/go
ENV PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin
```

It works like a charm.